# Pass a value dynamically to the declaring object/variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to assign a name of the dataframe dynamically and I am failing.

The code below assigns it to the variable DataFrame_Name and not the value of the DataFrame_Name

```
for i in range(0, len(Required_Reports_df)):
    ReportName = Required_Reports_df.iloc[i]['Report Name']
    ReportPath = Required_Reports_df.iloc[i]['Report Path']
    DataFrame_Name = ReportName + "_df"
    DataFrame_Name  = pd.read_excel (ReportPath, skiprows=[ReportStartingHeaderRow])
```

What are my options here, other than having a dictionary. If Dictionary is the best option, how can I use dictionary here - Should I consider creating the dictionary with another for loop before this.

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to assign a name of the dataframe dynamically....If Dictionary is the best option

A dictionary is indeed recommended practice:

```
dfs = {}  # define empty dictionary to store your dataframes

# construct iterable of name, path pairs
zipper = zip(Required_Reports_df['Report Name'], Required_Reports_df['Report Path'])

# iterate name, path pairs and add items to dictionary
for name, path in zipper:
    dfs[name] = pd.read_excel(path)
```

Once you are familiar with this pattern, you can rewrite more efficiently as a dictionary comprehension:

```
dfs = {name: pd.read_excel(path) for name, path in zipper}
```